# Fabric js render of big image gives pixelated results

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I have to fit a big image (8000x6500) into a 800x650 canvas
When I try to render the image simply using `canvas.add()` and having the image render at its 100% scale the resulting image is much more pixelated/blurred compared to the original one.

This is the code I'm using (only the image is a little bit smaller but you can still see the issue):

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { imageSmoothingEnabled: false });
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://cms.web.cern.ch/sites/cms.web.cern.ch/files/styles/large/public/field/image/LHC_and_mountains-0503019-1-nice.jpg', (image) => {
    image.left = -3000;
  image.top = -3500;
    canvas.add(image);
});
```

you can see an example jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/al3x88/tvs58gdn/1/)

As a comparison, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/al3x88/57gq86ue/) is how you see it with konva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling `objectCaching` on your image will fix the pixelation issue. Fabric enables `objectCaching` on images by default, which means that your enormous image is being drawn on a massive offscreen canvas that's as big as the image itself and is likely hitting the browser's max canvas size.

More on fabric's object caching here: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-object-caching

https://jsfiddle.net/melchiar/edjguh3L/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: on android chrome even with objectCaching set to false the image has a bad resolution, could be because it's a mobile browser?

Comment: Which phone are you using? Looks fine on my huawei p10 running chrome

Comment: I'm using a pixel 2 XL, I'm doing some `image.scale()` because I've to crop the image and adapt the cropped region to the canvas size but I've tried to replicate that in the fiddle and it works correctly there.. I'm trying to debug locally using the remote inspector

Comment: Ok so, if you try https://jsfiddle.net/al3x88/edjguh3L/8/embedded/ with desktop I see the correct image, with the phone is blurred (just tried with a bigger image which is my use case)

Comment: Btw, even using directly the canvas API I get the same issue, might be a browser limitation, however I was using a library that was able to display the image correctly, probably was splitting the image in smaller images before displaying them

Comment: You can try this other fiddle too https://jsfiddle.net/al3x88/as2nxwtk/3/ why on chrome on OSX and android the images are completely different?

Comment: I've added a new question since it would've been out of topic for this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800439/draw-portion-of-an-huge-image-on-a-canvas-across-browsers