# How to retain jpeg image quality in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs to load a large jpeg (4500x3000) in a canvas that is fit into a 600x400 div with zoom enabled. Problem is the image in the canvas is resampled or something losing a lot of quality.

Here's an example. The same image in same size area. Top one is in canvas, bottom one is just CSS background.

Is it not possible to use the fabricjs/canvas with JPG and its original quality?

I've tried:

```
imageSmoothingEnabled: false,
enableRetinaScaling: false,
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52798525/7693185 (try setting `obj.objectCaching = false;`)